# Can we use env: variable in GitHub composite actions?

Tags: github-actions

My requirement is to use variables having values that are pre-defined like `myjavahome: C:\Program Files\Java` and use it at several steps inside a composite action.

I have a GitHub composite action like below:

```
name: 'Print variable Composite Action'

inputs:
  input1:
    description: 'Input 1'
    required: false

runs:
  using: 'composite'
  steps:
    - name: Step 1
      run: |
        echo "Input 1: ${{ inputs.input1 }}"
```

and it has several steps.

Can I have `env:` variable value which can be used throughout the composite and it should not be overwritten by a passed value?

I tried for example the below but it should not print the variable's value.

```
name: 'Print variable Composite Action'

env:
  installpath: 'C:\Program Files\java'
inputs:
  input1:
    description: 'Input 1'
    required: false

runs:
  using: 'composite'
  steps:
    - name: Step 1
      run: |
        echo "Input 1: ${{ inputs.input1 }}"
        echo "installpath is ${{ env.installpath }}"
```

How can I get the value for `installpath`?

Comment: Typo: Move `env` under `steps`. See [`runs.steps[*].env`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#runsstepsenv).

Comment: @Azeem what if i have to use that same variable in 20 different steps in the same composite?

Comment: You can set it to `$GITHUB_ENV` in the first step and then use that in all the subsequent steps with `env` context. Alternatively, you can move all your functionality to a separate Bash script too with only one step to configure for `env` ([example](https://github.com/iamazeem/substitute-action/blob/b3bad24a0744ebd2dd8bf4b02522d246bb6a4815/action.yml#L37-L49)),

Comment: Also, notice that `${{ env.something }}` can be simplified to `$something`.

Comment: Expanding user-provided input like `${{ inputs.input1 }}` makes you vulnerable to injection vulnerabilities; it's safer to set the value in the environment of the step and then reference the environment variable, see [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions#understanding-the-risk-of-script-injections).